# Open Kubuntu terminal with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, kubuntu

How to setup custom keyboard shortcut to launch terminal on KUbuntu?

PS. I have tried setting up shortcut that would issue `xterm` command, but that shows raw terminal, that looks a lot differently from the one that can be opened from the menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 18):

I didn't have CTRL+ALT+T by default after a fresh install of Kubuntu 12.04

Here's how I assigned in.. right-click the Kickoff Application launcher icon -> Edit Applications -> System -> Konsole -> Advanced Tab -> Current Shortcut Key

Comment: The "Kickoff Application Launcher" is the blue "K" button icon usually at the far left of the "Panel" bar usually at the bottom of the screen. For ex-Windoze users, it's the "start button".

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem and I found it:

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Kubuntus integration of KDE is broken and normal keyboard associations in KDE (like associating from "Edit applications" on the start menu) don't work in Kubuntu, but the shortcuts under "Shortcuts" > "Custom shortcuts" does work.

Answer (score 1):

The one from the menu is called "Konsole" so use whatever keybinding you have for the quick launcher and then type Konsole and it will come up as a choice and you are good to go.

[image: Screenshot of Konsole/Terminal in KDE quicklauncher]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> opens a konsole window.

Comment: I have Kubuntu and this doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is not a default mapping in Kubuntu!

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how I had that?  I don't remember changing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 with Plasma version 5.12.7, and the keyboard shortcut for terminal is switched off by default.

I didn't use KDE menu editor solution as I got a conflict warning message when I tried to edit the 'Current shortcut key'.
It said *"The shortcut 'Ctrl+Alt+T' conflicts with the following combination: Shortcut 'Ctrl+Alt+T' in Application KDE Daemon for action Run Konsole"*

Made me think there's already a setting somewhere that is switched off, which I eventually found going through System Settings. (click launcher button, start typing system (for System Settings) click the link when it appears) to launch System Settings.

In the left panel menu, open 'Shortcuts', under the Workspace category,
open 'Custom Shortcuts'

in the next panel,
activate 'Example' button (it's greyed out by default - see the comments tab once 'Example' is selected)

Now you can click 'Example' to open sub menu drop down,
Activate "Run Konsole" button
Click apply and close out of the screen.
Now Ctrl+Alt+T works.
Shutdown and restarted just in case - Still works.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like Samer with these options u can see from these screenshots below

[image: here]

and in the advanced tab:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in details not just a Link?

Comment: Sorry, i will edit my answer soon.